# Make a search only field for WooCommerce products

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

OK so I know this isn't exactly a code-specific question, but I'm out of luck in my research to find a way to make a search only product in WordPress using WooCommerce. I have 10,000 products I need to have available to buy on the website, however the majority of them are very small and specific. SO I need a way to have products on my website that aren't visible in the catalog, but can be found by search, specifically by their part numbers. This seems like a common occurrence in the world of eCommerce so perhaps there is already a way to do this in WooCommerce and I'm just missing it. Or does anyone know of a plugin that will achieve this?

Anything will help, thanks!

Comment: You can set a product's visibility to search only. See the [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-10). WooCommerce already provides a search widget for products.

Comment: Oh wow haha thanks! @helgatheviking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are many plugins that can help you with this. Try for example this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-woo-search/

Comment: Thank you, I will check this plugin out for the search functionality. I'll mark your answer as correct.